# can not find module express --on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I use "npm install -g  express" on windows console.but when I try to "node app.js", it shows me the error"can not find module express",I had set the environment variable"NODE_PATH",but nothing happen  ,I need your help,Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Globally installed modules aren't accessible without full path. You need to install `express` in your project directory or it parents. [Check out documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) about module loading.

Comment: on windows,I take the follow steps:1.mkdir test-->cd test->npm install express,--->node app.js..still not work

Comment: @Vadim how to install in a dir?

Answer (score 3):

npm allows two options on how to install a module: locally and globally.

A global installation (done using `npm install -g xyz`) is for providing some tooling system-wide. Related to express this provides the global `express` bootstrapper that you can use to create an initial frame for your app by simply typing: `express .`. If you need help on what you can do with this command, check out its help parameter: `express --help`.

In contrast, a local installation of a module provides this module for a specific app. A local installation is always made to an app's `node_modules` folder. When you try to `require` a module, Node.js searches the this folder for the requested module.

Hence, it is perfectly fine to have express installed multiple times: Once globally for the bootstrapper, multiple times locally (once per app).

So, to cut a long story short: To make your app run, install express locally using `npm install express` and that's it :-).